# Read and write file in y android appication

Tags: android, android-permissions

I'm posting this after long search in google and stackoverflow.

I was trying to read/write a file in my application, I'm using the following code to do the same :

```
public class FileOperations {
 public FileOperations() {
  }
public Boolean write(String fname, String fcontent){
  try {
    String fpath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() +fname+".txt";
    File file = new File(fpath);
    // If file does not exists, then create it
    if (!file.exists()) {
      file.createNewFile();
    }
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
    bw.write(fcontent);
    bw.close();
    Log.d("Suceess","Sucess");
    return true;
  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return false;
  }
}
public String read(String fname){
 BufferedReader br = null;
 String response = null;
  try {
    StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
    String fpath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() +fname+".txt";
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fpath));
    String line = "";
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
      output.append(line +"\n");
    }
    response = output.toString();
  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return null;
  }
  return response;
 }
}
```

I have already added the following permissions :

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I m getting the following error :

```
10-20 22:09:54.101: W/System.err(11634): java.io.IOException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
10-20 22:09:54.101: W/System.err(11634):    at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:946)
```

Comment: You only need one of those permission as write implies read.  But you may have placed them at the wrong place in your manifest.  It also looks like you might be missing a path separator - log out the path you are trying to access.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. @Chris Stratton 
As you mentioned i changed my filename to "/"+filename and it worked.